# MySQL Insert performance degrades on a large table dued to the size of the primary key

Tags: mysql

Could the INSERTs be slow, dued to the size of the PRIMARY KEY?

We are using hash algorithm to generate the primary key for the table into DB.

For example: 178E1775000064A71F7B413AAFDBBE24BD93650D- Primary Key[ Hash Algorithm : SHA-1 Hash 40]

Comment: why isn't the primary key numeric?

Comment: I am working in the existing application, they are using hash function to generate the primary key..

Comment: Why are they hashing? Couldn't they just use an auto_increment numeric value as a PK?

Comment: I don't have any idea...

Comment: Why you dont make this key like another attribute CODE and make it Unique, so like that you can get the functioanlity of primary key with your own properties

Comment: @YoucefLaidani the issue is width not Unique. It already is unique.

Comment: Whats your table def (regarding the key) and what's the index type?

Comment: They could be slowed down due to the size of PK, but not to a point where you can observe it as a human. Define what "slow" is and how you determined that inserts are slow. Personal guess: your I/O subsystem is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably say yes considering that the [MySQL documentation on the speed of inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html) says that `INSERT` performance is affected by the number of indexes that you have. The primary keys documentation and [index documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) doesn't really say much about "complex" primary keys. I would maybe do some tests on some sample data from your table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key to see if you see any differences.